# How to print current executing JUnit test method while running all tests in a class or suite using ANT?

Tags: java, junit, ant, junit4

I have a set of JUnit Test Cases and I execute them from ANT using the [junit](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) task. While executing the tests, in the console I get to see only which test case (i.e. Java class) is currently running, but not the test method. Is there a way I can print the current executing test method? Or is there any other way to do this other than having my own JUnit test runner?

Sample Console Output

```
[junit] Running examples.TestCase1
[junit] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 2.835 sec
```

Instead I wish to get the output like

```
[junit] Running examples.TestCase1
[junit] Running examples.TestCase1.test1
[junit] Running examples.TestCase1.test2
[junit] Running examples.TestCase1.test3
[junit] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 2.835 sec
```

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: At times, one of the test method seems to hang. I would want to know dynamically which test case is that. Nevertheless, do you think there is any valid reason why we should not expect such a feature?

Comment: Yes-it's not useful in a general way. It provides no valuable information. In the general case it only matters what tests failed.

Comment: Which version of JUnit? 3 or 4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no good way to hook into JUnit. For a framework that was developed with TDD, it's astonishingly hostile.

Use a `@Rule` instead:

```
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;
import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 * Log the currently running test.
 * 
 * <p>Typical usage:
 * 
 * <p>{@code @Rule public LogTestName logTestName = new LogTestName();}
 *
 * <p>See also:
 * <br>{@link org.junit.Rule}
 * <br>{@link org.junit.rules.TestWatcher}
 */
public class LogTestName extends TestWatcher {

    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( "junit.logTestName" );

    @Override
    protected void starting( Description description ) {
        log.debug( "Test {}", description.getMethodName() );
    }

}
```

Notes:

I'm using a static logger. That makes the code execute faster but my main reason is that logging test names is a cross-cutting concern: I would like to enable/disable this logging in a central place instead of configuring it for each test class.

Another reason is that I have tools which process the build output and those are easier to configure for a fixed pattern :-)

If you don't want this, then just get the logger for `description.getTestClass()`.

Comment: For now, I guess this is the best and easiest way to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: Where does this class reside ? Say for ex in maven

Comment: @BalajiBoggaramRamanarayan: It's not an official class. You will have to copy into your code.

Comment: I meant to ask - if there was a specific location to put this class file in. Ex : src/test/java or src/test/resources. Anyways, I figured out. Thanks :)

Comment: @pinkpanther You need to add it to every single test class or add it to a common base class and then have each test extend it.

Comment: Does anyone have any update to this? It seems ridiculous that I would have to modify all my tests just to print the name of the test that's running

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `formatter` by setting type as plain.

```
<formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
```

**Or**

You can use implement Custom formatters by extending `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitResultFormatter` class.

Comment: Using `<formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>` prints the summary only after the execution of all the tests. But what I need is that while executing each test, the name of the test method has to be printed.

Answer (score 1):

Derive a class from `RunListener` and override the `testStarted()` method.  It receives a `Description` parameter from which you can obtain the test class and the test method -- e.g., `description.getMethodName()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `TestName` rule. Just add the following code to your test class:

```
@Rule
public TestName testName = new TestName();

@Before
public void printTestMethod() {
    System.out.println("Running " + testName.getMethodName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to create your own test runner you could try using the stacktrace.

The following Method prints the class and method name of the method that called it.

```
public static void printMethod() {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2]);
}
```

You would have to call this method in each of your test methods.

Comment: This is redundant call made on every test method. And is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `showoutput="true"` caused my junit tests to log output as the tests were executing:

```
junit fork="yes" showoutput="true" printsummary="withOutAndErr"
```