# ANT print currently executing test case name on command prompt itself

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ant, automation, command-prompt

1. If I am going to execute a suite of let's say 70 TCs then I am not able **identify that exactly which TCs is in execution on that particular time**.
2. Some time I doubt whether the right bunch of TCs are being executed or not and I need to wait till the execution ends.
3. I am using **build.xml** to execute my suite from *command prompt using ANT* tool.

I've gone through this link but it seems like it'll print test case name in IDE console not in cmd prompt.

[How to print current executing junit test method while running all tests in a class or suite using ANT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222376/how-to-print-current-executing-junit-test-method-while-running-all-tests-in-a-cl)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use `System.out.println();` and running tests using ant command then it prints the message in command prompt/terminal not in IDE console.Now the point is how can you print the class or method name.

To print class name:

```
System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());
```

To print method name, you can either inject `ITestResult` or use `java.lang.reflect.Method` .

```
public void test(ITestResult result) {
  System.out.println("method name:" + result.getMethod().getMethodName());
}
```

or

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

@Test
public void test(Method method)
{
    System.out.println("Test name: " + method.getName());       
}
```